# Skype core dump

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, skype

I got this issue after upgrading to 12.04 from 11.10: 
sometimes, it is not clear what trigger the problem, i start skype and I got this:

```
:~$ skype
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I **uninstall and re-install it** works for a while **but after** sometimes/reboot (not a fixed time) **same problem come again.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

I found that the problem is related to prelink so to solve it you need to exclude skype from prelink:

1. Add this line to  /etc/prelink.conf

   `-b /usr/bin/skype`
2. purge skype

   `sudo apt-get purge skype`
3. Reinstall skype
4. `sudo ldconfig`

More info on this bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/skype/+bug/1002187

Comment: according to man ldconfig on Ubuntu 12.04LTS: ldconfig  creates, updates, and removes the necessary links and cache (for use by the run-time linker, ld.so) to the most recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and  in  the trusted  directories (/usr/lib and /lib). ldconfig checks the header and file names of the libraries it encounters when determining which versions should have their links updated.  ldconfig ignores symbolic links when scanning for libraries. Sure etc/prelink.conf is the right place to add that?

Answer (score 2):

Temporary workaround

```
sudo  mv /usr/bin/skype /usr/bin/skype-bin
```

then

```
gedit /usr/bin/skype
```

and copy this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
exec skype-bin
```

Save and exit.
Then:

```
chmod 0755 /usr/bin/skype
```

It should work.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers. If you find that two questions need the same answer, then you need to flag one of them as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: This one worked for me on Kubuntu 13.04 and Skype 4.1.0.20. The accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Frederik answered:

> I also experienced this with Skype from Ubuntu’s repositories, but x32.
>
> I now installed Skype again from the official Skype package, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove (rename) the ~/.Skype directory as suggested here http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-4-3-crash-on-ubuntu-14-04/td-p/3219892